# ObjectResult StatusCode 500 be overwritten in production enviroment

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm integrating an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC website.

We have a jQuery ajax post call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url, // Patch
    data: { "dict": JSON.stringify(dict) }
}).done(function (response) {
    $('#resultSection').css('display', '');
    $('#errorModal').modal('hide');

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    $('#errorMessage').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
    $('#errorSection').css('display', '');
    $('#errorModal').modal('hide');
    var errSection = document.getElementById('errorSection');
    errSection.scrollIntoView();
});
```

The method it calls can be simplified as

```
public IActionResult Patch(string dict)
{
    try
    {   
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(dict);
        // list => dicKeyPartNumberPairs
        _dao.InsertDigitalAttaches(dicKeyPartNumberPairs);

        return StatusCode(200, new BasicResponse
        {
            isSuccess = "1",
            message = "Import Completed"
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);

        return StatusCode(500, new BasicResponse
        {
            isSuccess = "0",
            message = "An unexpected error occurs, please, reach out to ..."
        }); 
    }
}

public class BasicResponse
{
    public string? isSuccess { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

When we test `Patch` with Visual Studio, no matter return 200 or 500 the corresponding `done` and `fail` function can be conducted correctly.

However, when we publish this to windows server 2019 + IIS 10. If we return 500, the `StatusCode` object seems to be replaced by a fixed formatted content that leads our `fail` function out of order.

Running Visual Studio, the response I got is

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 06:01:05 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=chunks-2; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProviderC1=CfDJ8KoY9S8Jp9ZFgwT85XuiJe4h-nBFrYSgB4rlcPpfenAXMfnnl1z851TcK2wkDwihoUX_YodlwPjChm1fnFg0PiKV7dZ5PjFIBOJSuLfMDnggzX7BBmDyGaBXP7agSMW8EcSUcR6jZkJN2KdgmE0R5orvBJgYOOhngimpid-keEOTORrG-Nr1SQDAq14a121CwZcm7kStctZ-qef7PPLDrqiKf8NNZPQfDFX6k7huuEfCyQlal0NoCCuoxbH2rTLHD01qec_G1X6ZxCP4Sfol8R4l4WWgBcd9ea4HVAyxDSFB0twXkW726I7QUoa8Ec_2IVOXKqRGEzsc8_1odSE5hefdY7XDX4htS_ulYDCtkoHo294dfnm63yrOimQgNmdUvmPJ-0Y_F1Tj37faWEt6eUVVisqlnzDPd-rCfrp2RPuEZBLuoWgS_DosbOZpJM_9vEO7bNIeMIQ7S_OXnZoMV8kA3Y5bYRkY38E5luSCdJ_thQd5eFhw5j0__PnEq4TtD9bV7wpaYbnC4vgJR26-oMm1GUP19KxmsBUryMmyAJCmE-K5_2qq3v01JAwFK0HWeYcfJRmkmXPQMkirbg9168LmpBTG_39NmoLy8K10eQkSTgOt2bnDNh2izATyzLq0gHfINEkpxP54660MYAxuXtVWikZ5ksnKZ4ZLw4vjK8g8WUJFRNhYqQeACUyWl-0UXVYSd5ywunvx-cedWDzGMnuDciw5y2rxis5n1CzTMcaH-1VQHKKHE4d1lGkwL9gNDa6iCmz7-9FLh3CGaSmiBYXf48cZ3mjfImCJQfZjJtURRbaf8EwmA_UyOqXUa5MRNFYL_PmYtmwcSoGyrPY7klDnIbJLW_qF_qwiATGoRmLBODclOTvJfDFns6_HBMOyYLLdOLhTiuj8JveCOca0WTuU6Bo5PiKaTRuSgESpaFECnMh3_ok9lDcKOpqNHY71lL5V7L8FBfo4T_Oqk6JdGT4LUwzbGB2Izr-7QdSHLiEQe41gAu-jF7gvNfZVjXYcvkr4nGjUsxDYvP0yIQZUI3ha1ErwNTwPopilW_VidaAWLdg55WMLBOcKrI3X3UGaUuWJ8hCBwB-6BxPdYb2SQO4fjtVio1KwJhod_CY6_pGaWpxqEd6YlEsXViEa9jRfj1HKB1DuFmRftmuahpqaeBX-0qnrlk5hMgpya7fD358BJp3GKMa6qNyjbvUDGu2uDFppUZoLkrqlElydIrlSwjiAIAH1vd4pV9kvBOl6RWBSICfPpIz4hYTio4tZYGkuQaJNVovdrvLSD3w1inMFoEX4At_RzZ9v2vAqlXdVkQkMz14fOqAM0Ll72ZptIU-sdR6lyIiAx8mOxhqA6aXCzeFzlCVyTL3AGaZq6sDpd1c8Bh4lWReVWFK4AQ6i8I2jOPjRX-ricUVp4bHIqRp96QIB3XLoWDISVJXjQ9OkFNR4gDOWaitBBPfa0CmnzeMAr0f78b4NmB0UCbZQUfpARrENw82Hx5-8_V5aaHEk3QGJp5Pn_2QcATdsZC44NYusyZCv2pve-woYKBb3Qf317nRVARVWMfMGZcp8sBl6sE9VZmyiUfDwcW10ZZbRsBSf-ZC4HNTjvjvWsaN55aSuZUVRMpc3iORMTFGCsKQmVD2BXWSj4y-OsrEYBHE7TTfp7WscoGjRufb5mIqy9iX3wzjCM4ITUbOzjbIqdT5IxpVQaJ-yhhKxzjbk-jqnAlmXEiAKbUtMqSSmy_MMOUy2qCIkFkiGoHPhLK6cvNDVrs8r-cd65zcaXgpdNEqUv9RdKwu2WvM96ThYXDi_FerYHTit8MdIs3mJFA-iwWZYOiLNwU7m610kMho2dv9mMqz0jBL9tQV2PYwqPsTW2r1d5krXOdMaiGHH2xkPdCUZcXWCfWOTFL09JOaDFTY-tHOb2j5gWVRL6yPp_FjTvBhxFJXqL_wp_Drie46jjr4e17VFLVDli8R_tvy2U_TWMTmT8i9bfO-zN90cTUsoq8Fh_mlzYpWt567TYdJviAoxu0LIUp3RT1H5U-EeEihQbdZw2SsqG9OHCM6HLbzZhWP85n_A2yHouvuD1hnzz9ajrXdFSi7kDleZsZ4HIGf3SMuCIvDLO47PWo6hIMd4AMU0Q1yWAq7j7EUdsBxKtdiLjD57ZgmDUHMlrHsVjFh4SXiGUGamK5AzI5BeUguZ-gDu8QYqoz9vf943WCbr3Z2QvTfC65Wd97xR6JdgF2WMNUHyNcQjyQ4mEkD4nl6sZk8xQR5nyQUDrXQFuVqZmR4HaSRLt7wmKXkvp3JL-tZRcnMGDX4Y5yt4B-Q0f4WcFZUB-bpNBbnQGclSBWRnCSsj3eg_j0WTSqmzsKbO5HoifiLMPvOjN3UG5okRukFmJoxSxegHpUgkTiywVp6-mjleDYNyEJEBqKPNMvB_sWtU6AcnAQV_vEU-vqYwM-Us1on0qCsr7gruGuX7yy8Wlmuu8RqpwpwWmbLdeW_eOncgJ3syuRQkvsVkJzcCxsrES3JqK2Kefv9tqp8fv-KgKt1eyvMg4zaFlH7tQhE58e043ueRDMk4SzH9ulZhr6Lsy9xPbxHV1ZWAD8_ntgj_KYG6Mr8IPw85YJUHAdtGsrCqIxNjgo9E_8-u42tm7ZAXxjaMSHmytQgUhpfCw0qtmiKQoONpTVh1TdFv36OI8bQrnPjtMrHfpp41jxDQlYF2LQ51x9lRdMK3NPaOSSNvJsQomY3E7DRCMA-9vKmCYSLT1kVqR2sRqGDN0KXGXQVre0x1QnRVCHhwDsyeiuPEFdAPudreyggbsjvIi_c490_ArahwoJYPQXX5irMy0hSlFrGKtsU4Qzb8eD-HuwNpsXI3ncsxvvCJs9Pmcyrf0LaqdQw70GYcJYUA1Jby-WkImYZuqTYi7OqRl66tsC00SN11Y9-6WyOZXzfP2HZOokHdBxnIwd15zqQQZkRHJseXB5UH8E5ohFje-nKisL0AGrWMVC07SlF98gVU_c_mSukbZktfWDrWx_pwKilWsJCd0WvkKouyXmd0vSYGx_UtfyvmoPD2Z5Ecj2CZxW5l8s-pHUo7I8-GTrA-NUYCqR2QfOdkobgGpo-lmDR2T_xR2kgcGSJmPmLEysElsjcCrgudsvAeOP7i4nhTdEIaHRhrjfyRwjeEsEwR_dzxajLX2Xt9DPqT_p4a09yB8hCFdkj1P3uwn0wdg3I-aBrljDUfBxZweEFnRZXs8ac4_oVJ1S0Bm3zSgaHqV7NryeaZaVB3F1k05YjfIuYQ67w2t5L_Revjv5Ax-t0jcmpnqBKrbhxo-wP9yCPXJrRsngJn7lE1PvxeVTcgTlC9WmufZOX9BlL9ZBuSxFkcXhQ17CQR36UMf7esSAtApuvJxRqILNmDSCkWfGK8a7A-mVZu9e2yQqY8spFxvPiSMIiONDY726zCQ9FEW2AInWxSTjgED5d5EqTapHJycRU48csWIWRJWbseS1IACbjIu5KXbIQVbbYOenHMu8yQ-rMajeZ-jdyJCWfQsuer4pv-R-lSt_oxqjmhZKQc2a-J7is1NEDDfAdewPk1MjnJY2ww4uTAdIJhGP3btZvx5YZ85wSGmlkv1UGSZuDxeGgIfFDXV6f-llVd53c64IlBDRddfkDu6Ignp7_GDrr4AGWFJ0pwQPq6kiBni-2MSIvZvR9kdbhVL4Er5LohJ1jfxo_pABFFKGrfNATsEsxzWskK3kdBnbANhyNr-mk9Tl0skIfHUypspa4u7_ZiodLvUqLFxSJoGWxg-uWeRpWtRnhWJu26adsmaDX3LhF8wN7_cXUOCdGPd8c9QxO7mM6LWEf7n6QiYCi8_H__YCBZmwdgE1niDt-Aw5DrndRG9CEUSIz_3WSG3Ns2xt6LOHMHP35mXyzSKUf18ZbYp5zC_VK90z3ZHD7OP9I7jMsEeiFfJO2te0Gnh-pCUMrHVJyqp553cICCZcULKUJ9ptqN; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProviderC2=JRFdCZvqczu37uE_rVYi7_HCl4SHJE4hzzvEh-GLUA-GMTKuvwIUI0Jnxeis7dShmAezMKOX0nGHS6e-xvSUrTIYvMU-W4s2Wntzph2rzbVZcteOSD5QrrfoIStIb1S8ROkjGsbkOR2s9QZh0ceX7CpNxCfIsa2zDQVhjtJfjsYGTlgfsPwFxTzV-1vZ4kwUXZYq2nGdMEuzRE46In_TDO2Putfy4pFgbARUdEV-82EQ9JowT2FrPlXYPe1-vWreRN3kRqC0Han6QezlBQ2U9MnDojGBdk0gRTOXjDhdDkN4EE3HKGAn7lz0e5TGUPlmk_HmKcf_UMAY4o5YzkvnVt6m3JH13HlPCmIa3m8HepWeeEDYf6rPKccKwd5JU7JOTs83rAn2q7zEFHv_n03q7pIxdZ7urZPkr4i1OK_Ff2GE4t_YTVKVjI6X4xxH93rs5QXnp3paVZjjjinwbDzQTejhwckHodo7Qqr78kiqaE8dyR1JpmuMobo-2CjnMjR4p-hDjmkJHr2CcdjU575uw9yLfZzU5aKgbFQuO4s7vSjmYx_pzXQYk5vFyWsVTOVrycLNFX5Zuv22OroCp6YcdZpjHZp7qVeup5lRmsTpETjjz37x9HfRfRJwsmZpG0CINGATWKLbm5wREygwVicUdgeO8ukcVkXzSHtzMAXIWYi1KfmQRxmpnpojw-wIgNeW2Bt5Aq2l3ZGSErSK-B2flkyL2scSvk_qKaart5pZmasRQFjMNqsPrIkjrjczMgWyWT2SB1sFTSQrkt9OHQipAJpFidmfwwsHQEtabY0LXhn0nJYYvCh2bblpAs5UZYy1lRrE99z7eu2wmCzND-bmasRiA9Rh60qbnidUKa6-9keu-o8q0dWVSTV8IXOXCBJ2Ee-EnJDSu37gNwRqH9l5XFVl5g7OzNGm5oa2dgYfRqE64Z9Bb0HHty6hdf5Kw5kjVSdRTLtJoyNOpmthmZuKffQNf4uF-VCFeuv9D-cV7atewWv1Ea_50F7UgQLtfDQvvdz_nvFbMsMzvzfYeWIErnVVT03yV5WQFX_b6bW6XhP5JRe651te86F0jXhelu5UdRmc049DdgoWqqqZZU8nwK6nESWJbqG6zsG6Z-CvTqzvP0oy5VzIakFEL_ucslRjYr-1ViEP-Dqvgx0Xp9eFQA-3yp5FTuVWLwQTGZvanEAwWXC9NddqSL9uMLy4Bx8U-1Z3K6AXKpYqefysD_0PJTtw24AriOA91oXiMzjWpwJYeMmXUH4JTOvn1Z85lpg35HneDVbroAX8sniBuLJp-Wg-uvxBmcW1OFwfE-cgPgtRLJjowWtkW42oSpcPOJO0JmP9zAkihIuaydn9y4aGNV1rqP3CYW2_p8UtoC2H5eb6LOe8OnFuRCimoICUjok3cB8Rri34P38ecdT98P9S_5VqmCDiQp2d9KIORILA3cQrNxO9DhBbK3bBZBGqF2Cte9LgtVUvAQdP6QvKicChchX7TzBO_eSSBqG5w1vMETqBTA5Nlkp0g0DcZUpm3NX6eW5W_rN1eNacyQkv9XZ1KZ8H9lGf1ktEOmUbXuIAiyHeqywaY9wbtgIWPeQsjZBiY3HegcHAgwc5rmg40t2VPWwlMqj2UhpnFTcKa8cDN39tcdd51MLTP4xKK-lWVWjSBgX7TCd2krbms2QQecEL8YLw0LN4lwnGckLOCt4dFg0VaHa5-9slcOIos3DcpmbPPsXKQM8lgUaLZisWTUvSPF3LRjZANJhsCgWPpHRl52pJeRPEjex2oSQUZnNHj68BjRM88TFvDNiNpNm1-pIRsL6smt1PUaP0St99LIpvDUa65nn76mc5B9BZG4zfaLMKBRBnTgnXqwnpT3nM1uabL4IVpoyVPxUUBCdbLDwB9qeKQYXAhgKLZ-jNDTpJTSaV5qUjF5z7f4obW7RptlHeeF4-tH3FoyVjT_Ok_opfw5dPHWYTpx-dHtzqr6j-kg_IWMYTa_P6arrSM1rPhLbATCzQn49W53J4pafPqfo2Lce2ZdEH8rM23yvyjrP30A; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

79
{"isSuccess":"0","message":"An unexpected error occurs, please, reach out to the GIS OA3 team if the situation remains."}
0
```

But when hosting on the production server, the response I got is like

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Mvc.CookieTempDataProvider=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/PBR2ndPathWebsite; samesite=lax; httponly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 30 May 2023 06:22:46 GMT

4b8
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

0
```

What can I do to make `BasicResponse` pass to client as it works with Visual Studio? Or is there a way at least I can pass `message`?